# Ping Pong game in SFML

Tags: c++, game, sfml

I am learning C++ and SFML so I want to know if I am laying my code out neatly and if my code is efficient. I know this is not a full game yet but I want to know if I am on the right tracks.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "ResourcePath.hpp"

#include <iostream>

class Paddel {
    int speed = 3;
    sf::Vector2f border;
    sf::Vector2f size;
    sf::Vector2f position;
    sf::Vector2f screenSize;
public:
    sf::RectangleShape shape;

    Paddel(sf::Vector2f screenSize,int player)
    {
        this->screenSize = screenSize;
        this->size = sf::Vector2f(20,100);
        this->border = sf::Vector2f(8,6);

        if(player == 1)
            this->position = border;
        else if(player == 2) {
            position.x = (screenSize.x - size.x) - border.x;
            position.y = border.y;
        }

        this->shape.setSize(this->size);
        this->shape.setPosition(this->position);
    }

    void moveUp()
    {
        this->position.y -= this->speed;
        if(this->position.y < this->border.y)
            this->position.y += this->speed;
        this->shape.setPosition(this->position);
    }

    void moveDown()
    {
        this->position.y += this->speed;
        //100 - (600 + 5)
        if(this->position.y > (this->screenSize.y - this->border.y) - this->size.y)
            this->position.y -= this->speed;
        this->shape.setPosition(this->position);
    }
};

using std::cout;
using std::endl;


int main()
{
    sf::Vector2f screenSize(800,600);
    sf::RenderWindow Window(sf::VideoMode(screenSize.x,screenSize.y),"Ping Pong");
    Window.setFramerateLimit(60);
    Window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

    Paddel playerOne(screenSize,1);
    Paddel playerTwo(screenSize,2);

    const sf::Time TimePerFrame = sf::seconds(1.f/60.f);
    sf::Clock clock;
    sf::Time timeSinceLastUpdate = sf::Time::Zero;
    sf::Time elapsedTime;

    bool play = true;

    while(Window.isOpen())
    {
        Window.clear();
        sf::Event Event;

        while(Window.pollEvent(Event))
        {
            if(Event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                Window.close();
        }

        elapsedTime = clock.restart();
        timeSinceLastUpdate += elapsedTime;
        if(play){
            if(timeSinceLastUpdate > TimePerFrame){
                if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
                {
                    playerOne.moveUp();
                }
                if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
                {
                    playerOne.moveDown();
                }

                if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
                {
                    playerTwo.moveUp();
                }
                if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
                {
                    playerTwo.moveDown();
                }

                if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::P))
                    play = false;
            }

            Window.draw(playerOne.shape);
            Window.draw(playerTwo.shape);

            Window.display();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since I have only got up-votes does this mean that my code is efficient and that my code is displayed neatly or does this mean that someone else has to answer?

Comment: Looking at [all the other SFML questions](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sfml), it seems Code Review does not currently have enough active users who use this library. Unfortunately, people who are unfamiliar with the library may shy away from providing a review. You can help build the SFML community on Code Review by continuing to ask great questions and by reviewing or even partially reviewing other questions or even your own questions.

Comment: @jliv902 .. i agree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is fine but I would go with some thing like this, i have commented the changes

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <cstdint>

// for eliminating magic numbers
enum class Players
{
    PlayerOne,
    PlayerTow
};

enum class ScreenSize
{
    Width = 800,
    Height = 600
};

// SFML has tiny class for rendering purpose, it has only a one virtual fucntion 
class Paddel : public sf::Drawable
{
    // for member data perfered tobe started with m prefix 
    float mSpeed; // here is an optional you may use integer value
    sf::Vector2f mBorder;
    sf::Vector2f mPosition;
    sf::Vector2u mScreenSize;
    sf::RectangleShape mShape; // <-- now it's private
public:

    Paddel(sf::Vector2u screenSize, Players player)
        // member data perfered be initilaized as contructor's initilaized list
        : mScreenSize(screenSize)
        , mBorder(8, 6)
        , mSpeed(3.f)
    {
        sf::Vector2f size = sf::Vector2f(20, 100);


        switch (player)
        {
        case Players::PlayerOne:
            mPosition = mBorder;
            break;
        default:
            mPosition.x = (mScreenSize.x - size.x) - mBorder.x;
            mPosition.y = mBorder.y;
        }

        mShape.setSize(size);
        mShape.setPosition(mPosition);
    }

    void moveUp()
    {
        mPosition.y -= mSpeed;
        if (mPosition.y < mBorder.y)
            mPosition.y += mSpeed;
        mShape.setPosition(mPosition);
    }

    void moveDown()
    {
        mPosition.y += mSpeed;
        //100 - (600 + 5)
        if (mPosition.y >(mScreenSize.y - mBorder.y) - mShape.getSize().y)
            mPosition.y -= mSpeed;
        mShape.setPosition(mPosition);
    }

    // sf::Drawable has singe virtual fucntion for rendering, override it 
    void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const override
    {
        // sf::RectangleShape has its own defualt RenderStates
        target.draw(mShape, states);
    }
};

int main()
{
    // unfortunately strong type enumeration doesn't decay to integer value, so that we need to static cast it to integer type 
    // here we don't want to have a negative value for size, we should use unsigned int or use std::uint32_t which is declared 
    // in <cstdint> header file if you considered C++11 features.
    sf::Vector2u screenSize(static_cast<std::uint32_t>(ScreenSize::Width), static_cast<std::uint32_t>(ScreenSize::Height));
    sf::RenderWindow Window(sf::VideoMode(screenSize.x, screenSize.y), "Ping Pong");

    Window.setFramerateLimit(60);
    Window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

    Paddel playerOne(screenSize, Players::PlayerOne); 
    Paddel playerTwo(screenSize, Players::PlayerTow);

    const sf::Time TimePerFrame = sf::seconds(1.f / 60.f);
    sf::Clock clock;
    sf::Time timeSinceLastUpdate = sf::Time::Zero;
    sf::Time elapsedTime;

    bool play = true;

    while (Window.isOpen())
    {
        Window.clear();
        sf::Event Event;

        while (Window.pollEvent(Event))
        {
            if (Event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                Window.close();
        }

        elapsedTime = clock.restart();
        timeSinceLastUpdate += elapsedTime;

        if (play)
        {
            if (timeSinceLastUpdate > TimePerFrame)
            {
                if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
                {
                    playerOne.moveUp();
                }
                if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
                {
                    playerOne.moveDown();
                }

                if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
                {
                    playerTwo.moveUp();
                }
                if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
                {
                    playerTwo.moveDown();
                }

                if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::P))
                    play = false;
            }

            Window.draw(playerOne); // <-- we can draw Paddel object directly
            Window.draw(playerTwo);

            Window.display();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain to me what `static_cast<std::uint32_t>(ScreenSize::Width)` does or can't you on CR? also why have you changed speed to a float when it is always going to be a int? Thanks

Comment: @aPyDeveloper .. sure,,, i edited my answer.

Comment: I find you use of enums disturbing.

Comment: Sorry, missed my edit grace period by thinking too long about it:  Why don’t you use static constants in namespaces or classes? The fact that you need an explicit cast here for something which intuitively should decay (an integer constant to integer) should set off an alarm.

Comment: @JonasWielicki .. yes i agree with you i posted this as an alternative.. you may post an answer

Comment: Thanks for the edit. So we are doing that code to make sure that they are positive integers?

Comment: From what some people are saying should I use the enums or not then?

Comment: @aPyDeveloper .. it's matter of choice if you feel comfortable with using `enum class` thats fine or you can use regular `enum` instead ... btw `mSpeed` better tobe `float` for later use, to get what i mean, SFML has pong example written by auther of SFML library. here a link to how they did it - https://github.com/MORTAL2000/Ping-Pong/tree/master

Comment: Thanks for the pong example. May come in handy for the physics later.

Comment: @aPyDeveloper .. you most welcome